# Invalid column name in case statements in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a SQL query which includes the following SELECT terms:

```
SUM(CASE WHEN JobResponses.result = "true" THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [True],
SUM(CASE WHEN JobResponses.result = "false" THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [False],
```

However, when I use this is a SQL Server query, I got the syntax error:

> Invalid column name 'true'.

obviously `result` is the reference to the column name, so why am I getting this error? It seemed to work fine on SQLite??

Comment: use single-quotes for strings.

Comment: simply remove the quotes in `"true"` and `"false"`

Comment: Consider: http://rextester.com/NUJ28645  Basically `[]` and `""` denote object names so the engine can't find column called "true" in jobResponses.  But if we add one; no syntax error.

Comment: What is the column type of result? Is it string or bit?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're using " around true and false, should be ' single quote.

SQL uses " as a Column identifier.

Answer (score 1):

Using Single Quotes will solve the problem:

```
SUM(CASE WHEN JobResponses.result = 'true' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'True',
SUM(CASE WHEN JobResponses.result = 'false' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'False',
```